# Jenkins pipeline how to use if with agent label

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm new in Jenkins pipeline and I'm trying to figure out how the following could work.

I have two agents:

```
agent {label 'agentwindows'}

agent {label 'agentLinux'}
```

I want to have an if based on the agent label value.
Like this:

```
pipeline {
agent {label 'agentwindows'}
agent {label 'agentLinux'}
environment {
   var1=abc
}
stages {
   stage ('stage1')
       steps {
         script {
             if (agent.label == "agentwindows") {
               bat "uname -n"
             } else {
               sh "uname -a"
             }
         }
       }
  }
}
```

I'm getting a "no such property: agent for class: WorkflowScript"

Answer (score 0):

Sample pipeline code to achieve the same:

```
pipeline {
agent none
stages {
    stage('Test on Linux') {
        agent { 
            label 'agentLinux'
        }
        steps {
            sh 'uname -a'
        }
    }
    stage('Test on Windows') {
        agent {
            label 'agentwindows'
        }
        steps {
            bat 'uname -n' 
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Atta, thanks fr the answer.
The idea is to have it, changing dynamic and not having it hardcoded.
I need to have a single stage.

Comment: Jenkins doesn't support this feature yet.